# Request-URL in WCF Service with multiple IIS-bindings?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I have an IIS-Hosted WCF service and would like to make it available at several domains using multiple IIS-bindings on the same web application. Example:

- http://foo/Service.svc
- http://bar/Service.svc

Using .Net Framework 4 and its [`multipleSiteBindingsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicehostingenvironmentsection.multiplesitebindingsenabled.aspx) attribute, the service activates successfully. However, *only one* IIS-binding is used as a base address for the [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) and properties within the [`OperationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) always contain that address *regardless* of which host name was used to make the call.

So my question is: **Within a service method, how can I retrieve the actual host name that was used for the call?**

I know that I could use [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) with [ASP.NET Compatibility Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) to retrieve the actual request url but was wondering if there's another (better?) way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the [`IncomingMessageProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.incomingmessageproperties%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contain a [`HttpRequestMessageProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httprequestmessageproperty.aspx) object that contains all request details, including the correct host name:

```
var ctx = OperationContext.Current;
var httpRequest = ctx.IncomingMessageProperties["httpRequest"]
                  as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

var hostName = httpRequest.Headers["host"];
```